# How can I connect to a Bluetooth module using Delphi XE8?

Tags: android, delphi, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have with my delphi code found the device I want to connect to and display services available. When I do the DiscoverServices for the device I found the method returns false meaning it didn't started. I suspect that this is because the device is not connected.

Following the example in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#read I do the whole discover part but I have found no equal thing in delphi that does

device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback)

How do I go about to connect the device to my android phone in Delphi?

Am currently doing like the following

```
  FBLEDevice := FBluetoothManagerLE.LastDiscoveredDevices.First;

  FBLEDevice.OnServicesDiscovered := GetServicesAndCharacteristics;


  if FBLEDevice.DiscoverServices = False then
    Memo1.Lines.Add('DiscServ could not start')
  else
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Discover Services started');
```

SOLUTION:

You apparently don't need to connect in some special way as I though, the problem that my method won't start was because there are currently no services to discover on the module I am using.

Comment: Did you read [Using Classic Bluetooth](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Classic_Bluetooth) and [Using Bluetooth Low Energy](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Bluetooth_Low_Energy)?

Comment: I attempted using Bluetooth just for fun, and the demo in XE8 was severely broken, so I immediately gave up (had better things to do).

Comment: @LU RD I read Bluetooth Low energy. I have gone through the steps  in that link but as I mentioned, the DiscoverServices method won't start...